# Utilizar opción de SELECT seleccionada para filtrar una consulta SQL

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

Lo que necesito es que, mediante un select de proveedor, cargar los datos de los productos asociados a ese proveedor seleccionado anteriormente.

**SELECT de Proveedores** en index.php

```
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                  <label for="proveedor" style="font-size:11pt;" class="control-label"><h5>Selecciona el proveedor</h5></label>
                     <select class="proveedor form-control" style="font-size:11pt;" name="proveedor" id="proveedor" required>
                    </select>
                  </div>
```

**BOTÓN QUE CARGA MODAL DE LOS PRODUCTOS**

```
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="font-size:11pt;"></span> Agregar productos
                        </button>
```

Llamando el id del proveedor en productos_pedido.php

```
        $descripcion = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["descripcion"],ENT_QUOTES)));
```

CONSULTA SQL en productos_pedido.php

```
        $sql="SELECT * FROM  $sTable WHERE id_proveedor_producto = '$proveedor' $sWhere LIMIT $offset,$per_page";
        $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Lo que necesito exactamente, es una funcion como esta:

```
            function eliminar (id){   
            $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./ajax/agregar_pedido.php",
        data: "id="+id,
         beforeSend: function(objeto){
            $("#resultados").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
          },
        success: function(datos){
        $("#resultados").html(datos);
        }
            });
        }
```

Para pasar el id proveedor desde el SELECT "proveedor" en el index.php hasta la sentencia SQL en productos_pedido.php

CODIGO agregar_pedido.php

````
session_start();
$session_id= session_id();
if (isset($_POST['id'])){$id=$_POST['id'];}
if (isset($_POST['descripcion'])){$descripcion=$_POST['descripcion'];}
if (isset($_POST['cantidad'])){$cantidad=$_POST['cantidad'];}
if (isset($_POST['precio_venta'])){$precio_venta=$_POST['precio_venta'];}

    /* Connect To Database*/
    require_once ("../config/db.php");//Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
    require_once ("../config/conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos

if (!empty($id) and !empty($cantidad) and !empty($precio_venta) and !empty($descripcion))
{
$insert_tmp=mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tmp (id_producto, descripcion_tmp, cantidad_tmp, precio_tmp,session_id) VALUES ('$id', '$descripcion','$cantidad','$precio_venta','$session_id')");
}
if (isset($_GET['id']))//codigo elimina un elemento del array
{
    $id=intval($_GET['id']);
$delete=mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM tmp WHERE id_tmp='".$id."'");
}

?>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>CODIGO</th>
    <th>CANT.</th>
    <th>PRODUCTO</th>
    <th>DESCRIPCION</th>
    <th><span class="pull-right">PRECIO UNIT.</span></th>
    <th><span class="pull-right">PRECIO TOTAL</span></th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
<?php
    $sumador_total=0;
    $sql=mysqli_query($con, "select * from tblProductos, tmp where tblProductos.id_producto=tmp.id_producto and tmp.session_id='".$session_id."'");
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {
    $id_tmp=$row["id_tmp"];
    $codigo_producto=$row['codigo_producto'];
    $cantidad=$row['cantidad_tmp'];
    $nombre_producto=$row['nombre_producto'];
    $descripcion=$row['descripcion_tmp'];
    $id_proveedor_producto=$row['id_proveedor_producto'];
    if (!empty($id_proveedor_producto))
    {
    $sql_proveedor=mysqli_query($con, "select nombre_proveedor from tblProveedores where id_proveedor='$id_proveedor_producto'");
    $rw_proveedor=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_proveedor);
    $nombre_proveedor=$rw_proveedor['nombre_proveedor'];
    $marca_producto=" ".strtoupper($nombre_proveedor);
    }
    else {$marca_producto='';}
    $precio_venta=$row['precio_tmp'];
    $precio_venta_f=number_format($precio_venta,2);//Formateo variables
    $precio_venta_r=str_replace(",","",$precio_venta_f);//Reemplazo las comas
    $precio_total=$precio_venta_r*$cantidad;
    $precio_total_f=number_format($precio_total,2);//Precio total formateado
    $precio_total_r=str_replace(",","",$precio_total_f);//Reemplazo las comas
    $sumador_total+=$precio_total_r;//Sumador

        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $codigo_producto;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $cantidad;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $nombre_producto;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $descripcion;?></td>
            <td><span class="pull-right"><?php echo $precio_venta_f;?></span></td>
            <td><span class="pull-right"><?php echo $precio_total_f;?></span></td>
            <td ><span class="pull-right"><a href="#" onclick="eliminar('<?php echo $id_tmp ?>')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></span></td>
        </tr>       
        <?php
    }

?>
<tr>
    <td colspan=4><span class="pull-right">TOTAL $</span></td>
    <td><span class="pull-right"><?php echo number_format($sumador_total,2);?></span></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
            ```
````

Comment: Y cuál es el código de `agregar_pedido.php`?

Comment: @VickMuñoz ya lo agregué!

Comment: A ya entendí la función que pusiste del JS, necesitas una idéntica para realizar la consulta de los productos relacionados al proveedor?

Comment: Exactamente amigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te explico, tomamos el id del SELECT y le agregamos la función `change()` para que tome el valor cada vez que cambies de opción, después se va a ejecutar el `$.ajax()` enviar al valor a tu pagina donde lo quieres recibir y en esa página lo recoges así: `$_POST['valor'];`. con dataType puedes indicarle que tipo de dato vas a recibir, puedes hacerlo con JSON en tu php tendrías que hacer algo como esto echo `json_encode(array('producto' => $fila['producto'], 'cantidad' => $fila['cantidad']));` `$fila['producto']` serán tus valores de tu consulta una vez recorridas con un while o con el bucle que tu uses, espero haberme hecho entender, cualquier duda hazla saber, el HTML sólo puse como ejemplo compañías telefónicas.

```js
 
 $('#proveedor').change(function(){
 
let valor = $(this).val();

console.log(valor);
 
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "tupagina.php",
        data: {valor: valor},
dataType: 'json',
         beforeSend: function(objeto){
            $("#resultados").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
          },
        success: function(datos){
        $("#resultados").html(datos);
        }
            });
 
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
                  <label for="proveedor" style="font-size:11pt;" class="control-label"><h5>Selecciona el proveedor</h5></label>
                     <select class="proveedor form-control" style="font-size:11pt;" name="proveedor" id="proveedor" required>
                     <option value="telcel">Telcel</option>
                     <option value="movistar">Movistar</option>
                     <option value="unefon">Unefon</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>


                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="font-size:11pt;"></span> Agregar productos
                        </button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, no es exactamente lo que ocupaba pero gracias a ello pude resolverlo. Pura vida!

Comment: XD Bueno de algo a nada, no hay de que compañero, buen día! :D